# Postgres: on conflict with implicit conflict target

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Postgres 10 and 11 spec for insert says:

> ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action

I have a table:

```
create table c (
    e text not null,
    m text not null,
    v numeric not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (e, m)
)
```

and I want to do

```
insert into candle values (...) 
    on conflict do update set
            v = 5
```

but I get an error:

> ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name
>     Hint: For example, ON CONFLICT (column_name)

Why do I have to provide a conficting target? How to provide primary key or some other set of columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have multiple constraints and therefore multiple alternative actions.

You can simply specify the column names:

```
insert into candle values (...) 
on conflict (e,m) do update set
  v = 5
```

Comment: but that's a duplication of primary key. can i somehow just provide primary key there? or what should i do to just omit the conflicting target at all?

Comment: You could use the PK constraint name. Make sure the read the tip (warning) at the end of the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) section

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the `conflict_target` is optional, but only with `DO NOTHING`.

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html):

> For `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, it is optional to specify a `conflict_target`; when omitted, conflicts with all usable constraints (and unique indexes) are handled. For `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, a `conflict_target` must be provided.